# Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally

Tags: docker

I am running on a Mac and I still can't figure out why this keeps happening.

```
pie-cloud-tp-recon % docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started                                    

docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally a response like this means that Docker was unable to communicate with the registry over the network. There are various possible reasons for this.

- Firewall on your local system
- Firewall on your local network (common on corporate and school networks)
- Misconfigured, or missing, HTTP proxy
- Misbehaving TLS/SSL man-in-the-middle proxy
- DNS hijack

There could be other reasons. It's difficult to guess without more information, but you may want to talk to whoever is responsible for the network you're on, or look for other causes like local firewalls, software on your system that monitors and blocks traffic, etc.